# Syncfusion Essential ToolboxNuGetPackages doesn't exist when publishing .net 6 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, syncfusion

Hey all I am new at **compiling for .NET 6** so I'm not sure how to go about fixing the following issue I am receiving from when I **publish/compile** my new, **untouched**, **.net 6 c# project**.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: WinFormsApp1, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>------ Publish started: Project: WinFormsApp1, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Determining projects to restore...
2>The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\WPF\19.2.0.44\ToolboxNuGetPackages' doesn't exist.
2>The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\WPF\19.2.0.44\ToolboxNuGetPackages' doesn't exist.
2>The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\WPF\19.2.0.44\ToolboxNuGetPackages' doesn't exist.
2>Failed to restore C:\Users\David\source\repos\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1.csproj (in 1.51 sec).
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Looking in the settings for **Nuget** *I don't see any references* to **Syncfusion**:

[image]

[image]

Going as far as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\WPF` I get nothing in the directory:

[image]

Should I just **delete** the full `C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion` **directory** or is there some other place I can go to get that out of the list of things to compile? Where exactly is this reference coming from? I've done a **search** on my **entire solution** for **Syncfusion** but it also comes back with nothing.

Hopefully someone can point out what I am missing here so that I can compile without the issue any longer.

Comment: Can you view and show Manage NuGet Packages for Solution？ Manage NuGet Packages for Solution can see if Syncfusion is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you had installed and then uninstalled the WPF setup. During installation, we will update Syncfusion.UI.WPF.NET toolbox nuget feed path in the NuGet.config file.

Please install the setup if the toolbox is required or delete config file if it is not required.

Nuget config file location: C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config

Syncfusion.UI.WPF.NET NuGet contains all the UI controls assemblies which supports toolbox. If those toolbox assemblies are needed for your project, please install the corresponding package from nuget.org and compile again.

Please refer to below link to know more about toolbox configuration.

https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/utilities#for-wpf-windows-forms-and-aspnet-web-forms-platforms

While compiling your project, you need to refer the Syncfusion assemblies and set 'Copy Local' property as true for all the Syncfusion assemblies referred in your project. On doing this all the required assemblies will be placed in your output folder along with your application.

And you need to ensure that all the required Syncfusion assemblies also deployed along with your application.

If you are using the NuGet packages from nuget.org or trial assemblies\packages from the trial installer, then you should generate and register the license key in your application.

If the license key is not properly registered, below license errors will be displayed.
https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/licensing/licensing-errors

If you didn’t wish to register the license key in your application, you could download the licensed installer from your account once got the license and you can use that in your application. In this case, no license message will be displayed. Find below the details to download and install the licensed version of our installer,

https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/installation/web-installer/how-to-download#download-the-license-version

Installation steps: https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/installation/web-installer/how-to-install

Please follow the steps in the below KB article to generate the license keys for your desired version and setups.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8976/how-to-generate-license-key-for-licensed-products